# Consuming SAP NetWeaver Gateway Services from Android app

Tags: android, odata, odata4j, sap-gateway

I am developing an application in Android which consumes OData services provided by SAP NetWeaver gateway, I am using Odata4J library for consuming services.

```
ODataConsumer consumer = ODataConsumers
 .create("https://sapes1.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/");
```

when I am hitting [this URL](https://sapes1.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/RMTSAMPLEFLIGHT/) from web browser, it prompts "Authentication Required" dialog box where I have to enter my username and password and after that I can see service document, schema document etc.

My question is: how can I pass credentials with my request using Odata4J? Do I receive any kind of token after successful authentication for authenticating further requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass credentials with the call.
OAUTH,SAML2,X509, Basic Auth etc.

eg

```
   ODataConsumer.newBuilder(serviceUri).setClientBehaviors(OClientBehaviors.basicAuth(user,
   password)).build();


  //sorry this was the c# 
  var creds = username + ":" + password;
  var encodedCreds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds));
  requestHeaders.Add("Authentication", "Basic" + encodedCreds);
```

Normally the system (if configured properly) will issue a MYSAPSSO2 cookie.
This cookie can be re-sent with subsequent requests.

search for Basic Auth and OdataConsumer, a few examples will show up.

Comment: but how to add request header in ODataConsumer's object